# SweetAlert2 pop-ups not working in .php file

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

I'm trying to input pop-ups boxes as per SweetAlert2 in my web application using the following code:

Button Code

```
<td>
<a class="confirmation" href="employeeindex.php?delete_id=<?php print($rowEmp['emp_id']); ?>">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_delete">Delete</button>
</td>
</a>
```

SweetAlert2 Code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('.confirmation').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                const href = $(this).attr('href')
                $wal.fire({
                    title : 'Are you sure?',
                    text : 'Employee Record will be deleted.',
                    showCancelButton : true,
                    confirmButtonColor : '#77dd77',
                    cancelButtonColor : '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText : 'Delete Record',
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.value){
                        document.location.href = href;
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
```

I have also tried to use the name of the button as follows:

```
$('#btn_delete').on('click', function(e){
```

However, it's not working. Instead, no message box shows up at all, and the application cannot progress to delete the record from the database. Any ideas? I can't figure out what I'm missing...

Comment: Is there any error message given? Which part **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I firgured it out - had $wal.fire instead of Swal.fire ! Silly mistake !

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code is seem malformed:

```
<td>
<a class="confirmation" href="employeeindex.php?delete_id=<?php print($rowEmp['emp_id']); ?>">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_delete">Delete</button>
</td>
</a>
```

Change it to :

```
<td>
<a class="confirmation" href="employeeindex.php?delete_id=<?php print($rowEmp['emp_id']); ?>">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_delete">Delete</button>
</a>
</td>
```

And on your javascript, you seem to call 2 jQuery and sweetAlert2 script,
I think you should use the sweetAlert2 cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

Instead of :

```
 <script src="sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

And delete

```
 <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Since it already called here :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this will answer your question